# LINQ query nested loop with multiple select statements

Tags: c#, linq, xelement

I'm trying to generate XML, to create the nested XElements I am using LINQ.

However, I'm struggling to then create more nested elements based on the previous LINQ loop.

This is what I am trying:

```
List<MessageValues> desValues;

XElement xml = new XElement(ns + "Message_Name",
          new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "i", nsi.NamespaceName),
              from sr in subNames
              select new XElement(sr),
              from v in desValues
              where v.SubRoot = sr //need a way of doing this
              select new XElement(v.Key, v.Value));
```

Basically I need to know whether there's a way of nesting 2 LINQ loops but still selecting after each iteration.

Hope this makes enough sense..

Comment: Yes, that should work. What's not for you?

Comment: The line `where v.Subroot` is incorrect. This cannot be done, just looking for the correct syntax to achieve this

Comment: I have an answer - if it's not correct you might need to explain your requirements better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
XElement xml =
    new XElement(
        ns + "Message_Name",
        new XAttribute(
            XNamespace.Xmlns + "i",
            nsi.NamespaceName),
        from sr in subNames
        select new XElement(sr),
        from sr in subNames
        from v in desValues
        where v.SubRoot = sr
        select new XElement(v.Key, v.Value));
```

Comment: Brilliant, that's perfect. I really do need to brush up on LINQ.. just couldn't find the solution to this anywhere that I looked!
Thanks

Comment: @DNKROZ don't forget to mark as answer if that is, well, answer.